# Unable to perform Topic Modelling in Databricks with gensim mallet

Tags: python, gensim, databricks, lda, mallet

I am trying to perform Topic modelling on Databricks using the Gesim wrapper for Mallet.

I already have running code for the same on my Local system.

**Here is some sample code that already works on my local System:**

```
import os

os.environ['MALLET_HOME'] = 'C:/Users/Soumadiptya.c/Desktop/mallet-2.0.8'

mallet_path = 'C:/Users/Soumadiptya.c/Desktop/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet'

ldamallet_model = gensim.models.wrappers.ldamallet.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=id2word, random_seed = 123)
```

**Here is what I am trying to execute on my Databricks instance:**

```
os.environ['MALLET_HOME'] = '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/mallet-2.0.8'

mallet_path_new = '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet'

new_model = gensim.models.wrappers.ldamallet.LdaMallet(mallet_path_new, corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=id2word)
```

But this exits with the following error:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input /tmp/e091ce_corpus.txt --output /tmp/e091ce_corpus.mallet' returned non-zero exit status 126
```

Please note that I have already imported the necessary mallet files to the mentioned directories and the paths themselves exist. I'm assuming the problem is something with setting up Env variables inside databricks but unable to figure out. Any help would be much appreciated.